# Access control in a number of tags from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, asp.net-controls

I've such a structure

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Login ID="LoginControl" runat="server" onauthenticate="LoginControl_Authenticate" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:UploadFile ID="upFile"...
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" onclick="LoginButton_Click"...
```

How get access to FileUpload control in codebehind?
If there's no  and  it's simple e.g. upFile.FileName
But if it's in this tags ther's error:

```
The name 'upFile' does not exist in the current context
```

How to change it?

Comment: in which event you are  accessing upFile in your codebehind ?

Comment: protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: You're in the .aspx page's code behind, not the master page's code behind, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how that `LayoutTemplate` works, but you can try this:

```
FileUpload upFile = (FileUpload)LoginControl.FindControl("upFile");
```

Comment: It works...now is problem with javascript :)
var upF = document.getElementById('<%= this.upFile.ClientID %>'); throw exception

Comment: @Saint_pl - Probably the same idea, `var upF = document.getElementById('<%= ((FileUpload)LoginControl.FindControl("upFile")).ClientID %>');`